# Edit size CSS in this Circular progress bar

Tags: html, css

I use the following code: [bootstrap Circular progress bar using custom CSS and JS](http://webseotips.com/add-bootstrap-circular-progress-bar-using-custom-css-js/)

To get a beautiful circular progress bar, but the problem, I want to make it bigger, it appears small, and when trying to do that, it becomes bad, and this is a mistake from me, is from someone who helps, please :)

Thank you, I know that the solution will be simple, but I'm not a professional in CSS

[image]

Any way to make it big with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap circular progress bar has hardcoded values inside to be always 100px x 100px.

the easiest way to make it bigger is to use `transform:scale()` and make final chart rescaled to proper sizing.

See example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ywoat4s2/26/

The downsides of this solution is that after scaling chart may be larger than surrounding box, scaling happen as a last thing in rendering so you need to be careful to not overlap container which wraps charts.

Comment: Thanks, I do not know where to put `transform:scale ();`